# JSF: Keep/reload ViewState after Server Restart

Tags: tomcat, jsf, mojarra

In our JSF 2.2 (Mojarra)/ Tomcat 8 Enviroment i am currently faced with the following scenario (and some angry users):

1. Users are on a page with a ViewScopeBean that contains many Input-Fields.
2. At the same time a new version of the application is deployed using Tomcats default settings. that means the context.xml in catalina_home has the  part uncommented

   `<Context>
       <!--<Manager pathname=""/--> 
    </Context>`

which enables "session persistance accross restarts" and there is no parallel deployment configured.

3. that way users stay logged in after redeploy is finished, but the ViewScopeBean of that page of course got destroyed and all previous entered data is lost if it wasn't saved before by the user.

What is the most common approach to keep or reload exact that view state for the specific users, so that they can silently continue their work after server restart/redeploy?

i saw several similar threads covering this topic, but could not get the "real deal" out of it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In other words, your view scoped backing bean classes are not serializable?

Comment: of course, they are all serializeable!

Comment: Problem suggests that they're not been serialized and the only probable reason for that is that they are not serializable. Server shutdown and startup logs may contain clues.

Comment: yes. the logs only contain the famous ViewExpiredException for the specific view. so i wonder, if there is really nothing special that i have to control myself, like a ServletContextListener that manually serializes the data or something like that...

Comment: ViewExpiredException should not have happened in first place. The view scoped bean getting destroyed is not the cause, but the consequence of that. So we can ignore view scoped beans for time being. Next step, what's the configured JSF state saving method? Server or client? When set to server, there's really nothing else what you have to control yourself, but when set to client, there's one more web.xml configuration setting you have to take care of.

Comment: it is set to "server". i can post the full web.xml if it maybe of interest here.

Comment: I can only tell that this is not the default behavior. I recommend creating a sandbox project with most recent versions and most minimal code and settings and playing around with it. It should work just fine out the box.

Comment: ok, thank you. i will try it out and come back if a find the solution...